# Installing Git on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, repository, gitolite

I installed git with gitolite on my vserver using this  [tutorial.](http://www.countableset.ch/blog/blog/2012/04/29/ubuntu-12-dot-04-installing-gitolite-and-gitweb/)

But I've got a problem to clone the gitolite-admin repo to my computer.
The user is created with the option --disabled-password

But if I try to clone with

```
git clone git@<server>:gitolite-admin.git
```

he asks not only for the passphrase of my rsa_key but also for the password
of the gituser.

Anyone an idea? I thought the user is created without password and 
I don't know what to type in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> he asks not only for the passphrase of my rsa_key but also for the password of the gituser.

That means the ssh has failed to authenticate the request through the public_key (either because said public key hasn't been found on the client side, or is incorrectly registered on the server side, or the passphrase hasn't been provided, is the key is passphrase protected, by an ssh-agent).
In that case, ssh default to an account password for identification (wether or not the account is created with a password).

Do a `ssh -Tvvv git@<server>` to better troubleshoot what exactly causes the ssh command to fail.

Comment: thank you, I found out, that in my /ssh/sshd_config the gituser wasn't allowed to connect

Comment: wondering (FOR Sven) - which setting are you referring to - PubkeyAuthentication or something else?

Comment: @alihaider you should put `@Sven` is you want Sven to be notified of your comment.

Comment: @VonC thanks - I apparently need more coffee today (besides a brain transplant).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding

```
AllowUsers git
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file